# How do I manage staff capacity using Trello?

Tags: trello, project-management

I love Trello, but unfortunately at 35 people I cannot use it effectively without the following 2 features:

1. How can I assign a due date to a team member if I cannot see what their capacity or workload is?
2. I also need to see a highlevel schedule of projects.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can see their workload by selecting only their cards using the search/options tool in the right-hand sidebar.  As far as their capacity, You could potentially add a board to specfically manage that metrics. AFAIK, there is no way to store that in trello; if that is an important aspect of how you are using trelly, there may exist better tools.

I suggest you might want to ask on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ about whether you might be directly managing too many people and how you might improve efficiency in that regard.